# Not able to Loop Through all folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell, libreoffice

I am looping through a folder which has many sub folders and files. I want to execute a command when I go into inner folder (sub folder) only. But when I ran my shell script, it executed command only for the first folder. It does not loop to rest of the folders.

This is my command

```
for f in /home/SUPPORTINGDOCS_BK/SUPPORTINGDOCS_BATCH2/*;
do 
 [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && exec libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt *.docx
done

exit;
```

Please let me know if there is a mistake in my shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You `cd` to the folder, but never `cd` back.

Either, add

```
cd -
```

before `done`, or better, enclose the whole body loop into parentheses:

```
( [ -d $f ] && \
  cd "$f" && \
  exec libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt *.docx 
)
```

It will be run in a subshell, so the `cd` will not influence the current working directory of the main shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find for this:

```
find /path/to/search -type d -exec libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt {}/*.docx \;
```

The exec parameter will let you execute a command on the object found by the search definition; the string {} represents the object found, in this case the directory you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Vogel612 for suggestion about adding a detailed explanation